# Error: Computed value is too large, while trying to extract all the elevation values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, elevation, srtm

I am trying to extract all the elevation values of a region using the NASA SRTM Digital Elevation 30m data set as a CSV file. But it is showing the error FeatureCollection (Error)Computed value is too large,
centroid: Tile error: Computed value is too large and Error: Image.reduceRegions: Computed value is too large. I tried this same code, it worked for a smaller region. How can I solve this problem. This is my sample code

```
var srtm= ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
var dem = srtm.select('elevation').clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(ab);
// Create a feature collection of pixels in the dem
var pixels = dem.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'centroid',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
});

Map.addLayer(pixels,{}, 'centroid');

// Get lat long
var proj = dem.select([0]).projection();
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat();
dem = dem.addBands(latlon.select('longitude','latitude'));

// Extract lat lon
pixels = dem.select('longitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['long']), 30);
pixels = dem.select('latitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['lat']), 30);

print(pixels.limit(10));

// Export the feature collection as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pixels,
  description: 'SRTMtvm_30',
  folder:'geeExports',
  selectors: ['elevation','lat','long'],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3abad93ac7ccb17e71d5c1d5da48d256?noload=1

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduceToVectors` on the DEM is probably not doing what you're expecting.  All connected areas that have the same elevation will get collapsed into a single point (that's just what `reduceToVectors` does).

This is actually much easier to do than you've made it.  You can just call `reduceRegion` with a `toCollection` reducer:

```
var srtm= ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003")
var bands = ["elevation", "longitude", "latitude"]
var pixels = srtm.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat().float())
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.toCollection(bands), geometry, 30)
    .get("features")
```

Comment: i'm getting all the elevation values but not their corresponding lat and long

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the scale in the "pixel" for a whole country scale may fix this:

```
var pixels = dem.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 100,
  geometryType: 'centroid',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
});
```

Comment: Isn't scale the resolution of the data?